# Ĉu ekzistis aŭ ekzistas Esperanta mono?

Tags: culture

Ĉu ekzistas internacia monunuo, kiu estas farita specife por Esperanto? Se jes, kie kaj kiam ĝi estas uzata, kaj kio estas ĝia valoro?

Comment: Ĉu vi volas diri ke internacia mono estas Esperanto mono?

Comment: Ne, la demando estas nur pri monunuoj, kiuj estas faritaj specife por Esperanto. Esperanta mono estas internacia mono, sed internacia mono ne nepre estas Esperanta mono.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

En 1907 svisa Esperantisto René de Saussure proponis la internacian monunuon "**spesmilo**". Ĝi estis dividebla al "**spesoj**" (mil spesoj = unu spesmilo). Ĝis la komenco de la unua mondmilito (do ĝis ĉirkaŭ 1914) ĝi estis uzata de la Ĉekbanko Esperantista en Londono, kaj de kelkaj aliaj bankoj en Britio kaj Svislando. Ĝia valoro estis ligita al oro: 1 Spesmilo valoris 0,733 gramojn da pura oro. Tiom da oro valorus 24,96 eŭrojn aŭ 29,43 usonajn dolarojn hodiaŭ (13a de decembro 2017).

Spesmiloj ne estis nur por Esperanto, sed ĝi ja havis fortan ligon al Esperanto. Ekzistis moneroj, kiuj surhavis skribaĵojn en Esperanto kaj bildon de Zamenhof.

[image: monero de unu spesmilo]

La Esperanta versio de la ludo *Monopoly* (Esperante: Monopolo) uzas spesmilojn por siaj ludbiletoj.

Pli da informoj troveblas ĉe la vikipedia artikolo [Spesmilo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spesmilo)

---

En 1942 oni faris la monunuon "**stelo**". Estis metalaj moneroj de 1, 5, kaj 10 steloj, kaj poste ankaŭ de 25 steloj. Ili estis uzataj en Esperantaj renkontiĝoj. Ĝia valoro estis tiel ke oni povu aceti unu panon per unu stelo. Sed praktike ĝia valoro estis ligita al la nederlanda guldeno: unu stelo valoris 0,25 guldenojn. (Supozeble oni uzis guldenojn pro tio, ke la centra oficejo de UEA estas en Nederlando.)

Oni ĉesis uzi ilin en 1990, kaj ankoraŭ eblas aĉeti la monerojn ĉe UEA kiel memoraĵoj.

[image: la originaj stelo-moneroj]

---

En la 2010-aj jaroj denove aperis monunuo nomata "**stelo**", ĉi-foje faritaj el plasto. Ili estas uzataj en junulaj Esperantaj renkontiĝoj por aĉeti trinkaĵojn kaj manĝaĵojn. Ekzistas moneroj de 1, 3, kaj 10 steloj. Ĝin prizorgas estraro nomata Stelaro, kaj la ekzakta valoro estas kalkulata laŭ komputilaj algoritmoj. Ĝia valoro estas tiel, ke unu stelo estas taŭga por aĉeti unu teon en la gufujo.

Steloj estas ĉiujare uzataj en IJF (printempa junula renkontiĝo en Italio) kaj KKPS (aŭtuna junula renkontiĝo en Nederlando), kaj fojfoje en IJK aŭ JES, se la tiujara organiza teamo decidas akcepti ilin.

En aprilo 2017 unu stelo valoris 0,2447 eŭrojn, do ĉe la renkontiĝoj IJF kaj KKPS eblis aĉeti 20 stelojn kontraŭ €5 en 2017. Ankaŭ aliaj monunuoj estis akceptataj. Laŭ la Facebook-paĝo de Stelaro, la tiama kurzo estis:
★1 = 0,2447 eŭroj = 0,8210 brazilaj realoj = 1,033 polaj zlotoj (kaj laŭ mia propra kalkulo tio estis 0,26 usonaj dolaroj tiam)

[image: nuntempaj plastaj steloj]

Pli da informoj troveblas ĉe la vikipedia artikolo [Stelo (monunuo)](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stelo_(monunuo)).

---

Krome indas mencii, ke ekzistas malfermitkoda ĉifromonunuo derivita de Bitcoin, kiu nomiĝas "**Monero**", omaĝe al Esperanto. Sed krom la nomo, ĝi ne havas ligon al Esperanto. Pli da informoj troveblas ĉe la vikipedia artikolo [Monero (ĉifromono)](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monero_(%C4%89ifromono)).

Comment: Ĉu indus aldoni ion pri la spesmilo? https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spesmilo

Comment: A, fakte jes. Mi forgesis pri ĝi. Mi aldonos.

Comment: Eh, kial vi demandas ion, kion vi tuj poste mem respondas?

Comment: @CyrilBrosch La ĉefa celo de StackExchange estas provizi respondojn por demandoj kiujn oni serĉas per Guglo ktp, ne nepre por respondi nur al la originala demandinto. Tiuokaze se oni havas demandon kaj faras la esploron por trovi respondon, estas utile krei demandon kun tuja respondo ŝance ke iu alia havos la saman demandon. Estas eĉ butono en la formularo por demandi por rekte respondi.

Comment: Ĝuste, mi uzis tiun opcion. Kaj cetere, jen blogaĵo pri memrespondi: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ Citaĵo kiu bone resumas tiun blogaĵon: "it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged." (Estas ne nur akcepteble demandi kaj respondi sian propran demandon. Tio estas eĉ eksplicite instigata.)

Answer (score 3):

Alia mencinda afero estas la sendado de mono pere de UEA-konto. La monunuo ne estis Esperanta, sed ĝi estis tre ofta kaj Esperanta maniero por sendi monon internacie antaŭ ol ekzistis Paypal kaj simile.

La Internacia Respond-Kupono fariĝis Esperanta monunuo dum kelka tempo.